# 'mat-toolbar' is not a known element, module import does not resolve issue

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material, progressive-web-apps

I'm developing an angular application. I cannot compile the application because I get the following error:
'mat-toolbar' is not a known element:

1. If 'mat-toolbar' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-toolbar' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
   I have checked existing solutions relating to the correct import of the modules, and they are imported correctly. For some reason the problem still persists.
   The following is the app.component.ts class:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Angular-Project';
}
```

and the following is the app.module.ts class:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {MatToolbarModule} from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import {MatIconModule} from '@angular/material/icon';
import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';
import {MatTabsModule} from '@angular/material/tabs';
import {TodoCreationComponent } from './todo-creation/todo-creation.component';
import {MatMenuModule} from '@angular/material/menu';
import {MatFormFieldModule} from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

import {MatTableModule} from '@angular/material/table';
import { Dexie } from 'dexie';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import { ProjectComponent } from './project/project.component';
import { UserComponent } from './user/user.component';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    TodoCreationComponent,
    ProjectComponent,
    UserComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MatTableModule,
    Dexie,    
  ],
  exports:[
    MatButtonModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatIconModule,
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MatTableModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

the class where the issue is highlighted is in the app.component.html class:

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
  <span>My App</span>
  <button mat-button routerLink="/todo">Todo</button>
  <button mat-button routerLink="/project">Project</button>
  <button mat-button routerLink="/user">User</button>
</mat-toolbar>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Where both mat-toolbar and router-outlet are giving me issues.

Can anyone provide me with a solution to this problem?

As mentioned before, all signs for the application to run smoothly are there, but for some reason this problem persists.

Comment: Are any of the components standalone? I doubt you need have anything in exports for AppModule. Exports is to make declared context available to any modules / standalone components that imports AppModule

Comment: No, none of the components are standalone

Comment: Mat toolbar imports looks correct assuming angular material library is installed. If router-outlet is giving issues it’s probably worth checking AppRoutingModule (exporting RouterModule?) and routes. And if no issues reset and reload environment